# stop google maps from spinning the map

Tags: google-maps

I used to be able to keep north up. Now not only does north move, sometimes the map will spin. Usually when I try to zoom (at least this is when I notice it). Even when it does not spin, the map rotates to put direction of travel up. This is confusing: I feel that I never know where I am.

**Is there a way to force north to stay up? How do I activate it?**

This is important to me, because last night I had to stop for 5 minutes, to figure out where I was, and which way to go next. (the spinning made me lost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Maps (Android version 10.49.2, also tested on 8.1.0). Enter maps' and access the **Settings** menu by pressing the profile icon at the top-right corner. Scroll down and press the **Navigation settings**, then scroll down to **Map display** section, and switch on **Keep map north up**.

Comment: Confirmed to work on android 8.1